App Store Connect error - The Product ID you entered is already being used by another subscription
I started to setup an In-App Purchase using App Store Connect. So I created a Subscription Group and included a first Subscription. After that, I deleted by mistake the just created subscription. Creating it again produced this error:
The Product ID you entered is already being used by another subscription.
What the message says is not correct!
I don't use the Product ID in another subscription!
The product is (of course) not submitted yet. All Google/SO searches regarding similar issues talk about submitted Product IDs not being reusable. That's not the case here. Some other posts also mention that Product IDs cannot be reused, but there the error messages differ from mine above.
I'd like to keep my Product ID naming scheme.
What can I do to use the Product ID again?

Having same problems

I didn't manage to solve this issue. I ended up changing my naming scheme after all. Sorry for no better news ...

Having similar issue with Playstore
